# How do I solve PostgreSQL "Aborted (core dumped)" error?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I am trying to install postgreSQL-9.6.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. But when I am running '***initdb***' to create database cluster, it shows error.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/install
$ make
$ make install
$ initdb -U user1 -D /path/to/install/data
```

When I run the '***initdb***', it shows the following error:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
child process exited with exit code 134
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/path/to/install/data"
```

Any help?

Comment: If you're building from source, its usually a good idea to run [`make check`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/regress-run.html) before you install it (this goes for anything you build ...)

Comment: yes I ran the `make check`, it shows `pg_regress: initdb failed`

Comment: `$ initdb -U user1 `Is user1 the owner of the postgres binaries? -->> run initdb as user=postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit status 134 means that the process was called by a `SIGABRT` signal, since that signal has number 6, and 128 + 6 = 134.

Your process probably failed an `assert(3)` assertion. Did you `./configure --with-cassert`?

Try to read the core dump with `gdb` and use `bt` to get a back trace. That should tell you where exactly execution failed, so you can fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried with `--with-cassert` but problem not solved yet. same error shows. thanks.

Comment: Building `--with-cassert` will *cause* such an error if there is something wrong, but that is a good idea in your case. Get a backtrace from the stack dump!